# NaCI netmf supported by the GHI G400-S board?

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-micro-framework, nacl-cryptography

I have a G400-S Raptor from GHI.

I stumbled across the NaCI netmf library(http://www.mountaineer.org/resources/tidbits/using-the-nacl-crypto-library/)while searching for netmf C# Encryption examples. The netmf NaCI library seems to be advertised for the mountaineer boards and was wondering if the netmf NaCI library will work on the GHI G400-S board?

Comment: Interesting stuff even though I'm not so much into embedded (unless you count smart cards, in that case, pretty much). It does seem to be *part of the firmware* provided by Mountaineer instead of a separate download, so I guess the answer is likely that you either have it, or not. The site says that it thinks about proposing it for the Gadgeteer API, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Why not ask the Mountaineer group instead of StackOverflow?